# How to expose an NLTK based ML(machine learning) Python Script as a Web Service?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cherrypy

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. In the past while working on Java platform, I used to write Java codes(say, to push or pull data from MySQL database etc.) then create a war file which essentially bundles all the class files, supporting files etc and put it under a servlet container like Tomcat and this becomes a web service and can be invoked from any platform.

In my current scenario, I've majority of work being done in Java, however the Natural Language Processing(NLP)/Machine Learning(ML) part is being done in Python using the NLTK, Scipy, Numpy etc libraries. I'm trying to use the services of this Python engine in existing Java code. Integrating the Python code to Java through something like Jython is not that straight-forward(as Jython does not support calling any python module which has C based extensions, as far as I know), So I thought the next option would be to make it a web service, similar to what I had done with Java web services in the past. Now comes the actual crux of the question, how do I run the ML engine as a web service and call the same from any platform, in my current scenario this happens to be Java. I tried looking in the web, for various options to achieve this and found things like CherryPy, Werkzeug etc but not able to find the right approach or any sample code or anything that shows how to invoke a NLTK-Python script and serve the result through web, and eventually replicating the functionality Java web service provides. In the Python-NLTK code, the ML engine does a data-training on a large corpus(this takes 3-4 minutes) and we don't want the Python code to go through this step every time a method is invoked. If I make it a web service, the data-training will happen only once, when the service starts and then the service is ready to be invoked and use the already trained engine.

Now coming back to the problem, I'm pretty new to this web service things in Python and would appreciate any pointers on how to achieve this .Also, any pointers on achieving the goal of calling NLTK based python scripts from Java, without using web services approach and which can deployed on production servers to give good performance would also be helpful and appreciable. Thanks in advance.
Just for a note, I'm currently running all my code on a Linux machine with Python 2.6, JDK 1.6 installed on it.

Comment: Hi @alphaGeek I know this post is too old, but now I am struck with the very similar requirement. By any chance did you resolve this with a solution. My thought is to use Flask in Python (Need to learn Flask) but not sure whether that helps. Any inputs on this ?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to build an XML-RPC server, but you may wish to fork a new process for each connection to prevent the server from seizing up. I have written a detailed tutorial on how to go about this: https://speakerdeck.com/timclicks/case-studies-of-python-in-parallel?slide=68.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll take a look and reply back. BTW, I've a quick question. Can this method allow me to run the NLTK based Python engine as a web service and will be able to handle at the very least 100 of web service calls per sec?

Answer (score 0):

NLTK based system tends to be slow at response per request, but good throughput can be achieved given enough RAM.

Comment: Yes, I agree to that statement. Would you like sharing your experiences in this regard? Say we have a Sentiment engine that can potentially handle 1000s of requests per sec, what should be the idea amount of RAM and other machine configurations? any ballpark figure? Regarding NLTK, one of the reasons is ease of use, large number of supported library, support community and implicit Python platform support.

Comment: NLTK needs to load up corpus which requires large amount of RAM. Per instance the request rate is about 5-10 requests per second. Assuming you have 8 procs server with 8 Gig RAM. You could run 16 instances which will provide you a throughput of 80 requests per second per server. Load balance set of servers lets say 10 and it should be capable of doing 1000 requests per second.